# Delegate Command with Async Function in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, delegatecommand

In Xamarin forms we have delegate commands like this:

```
        /// Gets or sets the logout command.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The logout command.
        /// </value>
        public DelegateCommand LogoutCommand { get; set; }
```

Which is initialized in the constructor like this:

```
this.LogoutCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.ExecuteLogoutCommand);
```

Currently, the **ExecuteLogoutCommand** is return **void** type, but I wish to make it **Task** as it has an async task. But doing so breaks the initialization in the constructor. Any help here?

**Update**
The following link helped me: https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/

But now I get this error in my Unit Tests:

```
MobileApp.Core.UnitTests.Add.ConfirmationPageViewModelUnitTests.OnNavigatedToBackBehavior threw exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'MobileApp.Core.IServices.IAsyncDelegateCommand MobileApp.Core.ViewModel.Add.ConfirmationPageViewModel.get_GoBackHomeCommand()'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use async method in DelegateCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167307/how-to-use-async-method-in-delegatecommand)

Comment: @mihailduchev No, I tried this. couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: @mihailduchev I wish to override the delegate command method to have an option of returning task method. Is that possible?

Comment: https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/
This article help me a lot

Comment: Why not use a new command(the same function of ExecuteLogoutCommand) with return type task?

Comment: @Nenad, Thanks for that link, that helps. Although I get this error in my tests now:  Test method MobileApp.Core.UnitTests.Add.ConfirmationPageViewModelUnitTests.OnNavigatedToBackBehavior threw exception: 
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'MobileApp.Core.IServices.IAsyncDelegateCommand MobileApp.Core.ViewModel.Add.ConfirmationPageViewModel.get_GoBackHomeCommand()'.